# How to display different color in annotation point in map?

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

Can't display color of annotation point in map , how it could be solved here's my code .i declared even function of color in MKPointAnnotation even i can't change the color , is there i have missed any codes ??

```
class NearbyViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

    @IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!
    var schoolMap : [schools] = []

    var collegeMap : [Colleges] = []

    var universityMap : [University] = []

    class MyPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
        var pinTintColor: UIColor?
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       getschoolMapJson()
        getcollegeMapJson()
        getuniversityMapJson()

        menu.target = self.revealViewController()
        menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.00
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()





    }

    override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     mapview.reloadInputViews()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       mapview.reloadInputViews()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {

        let location = locations[0]
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let mylocation  = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mylocation, span)
        mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.mapview.showsUserLocation = true

    }



    func getschoolMapJson(){
        if (schoolMap.count > 0){
            return
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/schools")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print("success api",data)
                let myresponse = JSON(data)

                /*for i in 0..<self.myresponse.count{
                 let schools_data = schools(schoolJson:self.myresponse[i])
                 self.schooldata.append(schools_data)

                 }*/
                for school in myresponse.array!{
                    let schoolsObj = schools(schoolJson: school)


                    //Add Pin
                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((schoolsObj.latitude) , (schoolsObj.longitude))
                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0, 10.0)
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                    self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = location
                    annotation.title = schoolsObj.name

                    let pincolor = MyPointAnnotation()
                    pincolor.pinTintColor = .blue
//                    MKPinAnnotationColor.green
//                  let pinC =  MKPinAnnotationView.greenPinColor()

//                    self.mapview.addAnnotation(pinC as! MKAnnotation)
                    self.mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)

                    self.schoolMap.append(schoolsObj)

                }
//                self.mapview.reloadInputViews()
            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }
    func getcollegeMapJson(){
        if (collegeMap.count > 0){
            return
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/colleges")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print("success api",data)
                let myresponse = JSON(data)

                /*for i in 0..<self.myresponse.count{
                 let schools_data = schools(schoolJson:self.myresponse[i])
                 self.schooldata.append(schools_data)

                 }*/
                for college in myresponse.array!{
                    let collegeObj = Colleges(collegeJson: college)


                    //Add Pin
                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((collegeObj.latitude) , (collegeObj.longitude))
                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0, 10.0)
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                    self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = location
                    annotation.title = collegeObj.name
                    self.mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)

                    self.collegeMap.append(collegeObj)

                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }

    func getuniversityMapJson(){
        if (universityMap.count > 0){
            return
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/universities")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print("success api",data)
                let myresponse = JSON(data)

                for university in myresponse.array!{
                    let universityObj = University(universityJson: university)


                    //Add Pin
                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((universityObj.latitude) , (universityObj.longitude))
                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0, 10.0)
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                    self.mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = location
                    annotation.title = universityObj.name
                    self.mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)

                    self.universityMap.append(universityObj)

                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> I am confused to display annotation point color i tried in many ways
>   but can't do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following function. I hope this will solve your issue.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

           var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "myAnnotation") as? MKPinAnnotationView  

           if annotationView == nil {

               annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotation")
           } else {
               annotationView?.annotation = annotation
           }
           if let annotation = annotation as? MyPointAnnotation {
               annotationView?.pinTintColor = annotation.pinTintColor
           }
           return annotationView
       }
```

Comment: Sure. take your time